# PDF metadata when using XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, hyperref, metadata

I have following document that sets up PDF metadata using `\hypersetup`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfproducer={My producer},%
            pdfauthor={My author},%
            pdftitle={My title},%
            pdfcreator={My creator}
}
\begin{document}
Contents of the document
\end{document}
```

When this document is compiled with `pdflatex` all 4 fields of PDF metadata are created as specified.

However when document is compiled with `xelatex`, "Creator" value is set to `xdvipdfmx (0.7.9)`.

To change it, I use `pdftk` to dump metadata to a file, change it and then update PDF file with new metadata.

However, I am wondering if there is any way to set this "Creator" metadata directly in document, so that it is included in metadata of PDF generated with `xelatex`.

Comment: In the next xdvipdfmx, based on the present or later
sources in the TeX Live SVN, you can define them yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Akira Kakuto suggested in the comment, up-to-date version of `xdvipdfmx` behaves "correctly" and does not overwrite hypersetup value for "Creator".

To obtain more up-to-date version of `xdvipdfmx` you need to install `TeXLive 2015` or other up-to-date distribution.

Easy to follow instructions on how to do this on Ubuntu can be found in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373/37364) (I did this and metadata is correct). On Windows, it can be installed by [following instructions here](https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html) which basically comes to using `install-tl-windows.exe` installer (I didn't test it). For Mac OS X, [this should work](https://tug.org/mactex/) (also not tested by me).

**If metadata is still overwritten with TeXLive 2015, make sure that your PATH is set correctly and that you are in fact using up-to-date distribution instead of older, "stock" version that you have installed previously.** You can check that with:

```
xelatex --version
```

that should output something like:

```
XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (TeX Live 2015)
```